# Android Networking Exception: Connection reset by peer

Tags: java, android

I have an Android application where I connect frequently to a web service that I control using SSL exclusively. The first thing a user does that results in network activity is login and I currently use the Ion library for this although I tend to think my issue is not specific to Ion. This works as expected except for one specific user that has limited all internet access on the Android device to only work with my web service. They have done this by using their router to create a firewall that blocks all traffic except the specified domains. When this firewall is turned on they can't login via the app because of the following error:

java.net.SocketException
recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

They can use the browser to go to my website and access the same web service with the firewall turned on and everything works fine. In addition, they can turn the firewall off, login successfully (i.e. successfully initial the first connection), turn it back on and subsequent network connections continue to work. The user can even log off and log back in without issue. It continues to work with the filter on until they quit the app. When they then restart the app and try to login the error returns. This seems like very odd behavior and I'm not entirely sure it is an ion issue but I'm not sure what to do. Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this issue?

**UPDATE:**

Per a comment, I tested my application with Volley. It does appear that Volley works with the filter turned on. I would prefer to stick with Ion though due to some of its other feature so if anyone has any ideas on how to make Ion work in this scenario I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Ion library uses SPDY or HTTP/2 protocol which keeps the connection open. I may be wrong, there is a chance that a connection is kept open for too long and hence this exception. If possible, try with other libraries like Retrofit or Volley.